# Can't run jupyter lab kernel

Tags: python-3.x, kernel, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to run jupyter lab but the kernel is not connecting and I am not too sure the reason why. Any help will be appreciated thank you so much! This is the error I am getting:

```
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
[W 2022-02-11 09:54:20.931 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 2022-02-11 09:54:20.931 ServerApp] Kernel c9bb27e5-56fc-4daf-9631-306d5d277217 died, removing from map.
[W 2022-02-11 09:54:20.949 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 2022-02-11 09:54:20.949 ServerApp] Kernel d2ab9d87-1ddd-4cdb-a7a7-3bfaf3e91fc0 died, removing from map.
[W 2022-02-11 09:54:20.960 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 2022-02-11 09:54:20.961 ServerApp] Kernel b17914dd-d148-4d22-af26-f1a0a9f6149e died, removing from map.
[W 2022-02-11 09:54:20.972 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 2022-02-11 09:54:20.972 ServerApp] Kernel b37ce6bf-f2cb-428d-8188-f6b41ab3309e died, removing from map.
[W 2022-02-11 09:55:05.901 ServerApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from b37ce6bf-f2cb-428d-8188-f6b41ab3309e
[E 2022-02-11 09:55:05.904 ServerApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: b37ce6bf-f2cb-428d-8188-f6b41ab3309e)
[W 2022-02-11 09:55:06.196 ServerApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from c9bb27e5-56fc-4daf-9631-306d5d277217
[E 2022-02-11 09:55:06.197 ServerApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: c9bb27e5-56fc-4daf-9631-306d5d277217)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda to run Python then this post might be useful ...

http://www.techanswersweb.com/kernel-error-jupyter-notebook

Comment: I've tired but the kernel is still not working despite creating a new environment. This is the error!

Comment: Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/3ceb5f8a-6a23-42ef-82e8-8ae02aa3784f/channels?session_id=f6bb5aa26c7a4384b4a712ceee773ea8 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/3ceb5f8a-6a23-42ef-82e8-8ae02aa3784f/channels?session_id=f6bb5aa26c7a4384b4a712ceee773ea8', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/saraang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 956, in _accept_connection
        await open_result
      File "/Users/saraang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 349, in __wakeup
        future.result()
    tornado.util.TimeoutError: Timeout

Comment: Sorry - that's the limit of my knowledge :( ... anyone else ??